# Скрипт не отправляет данные о загруженных фото JavaScript PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Второй день мучений, подскажите кто может в чем ошибка.

Есть превью для загружаемых фотографий, не могу понять почему он выдает ошибку error ->4  в массиве с фото.

Остальную информацию с формы загружает, фотографии нет.

```
<form name="Download" id="Download"  method="post" action="S.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="number" name="run" value="run">

  
     <input type="file" name="img[]"  id="addImages" multiple="">


    <input type="hidden" name="zaza" value="azaza">
 
    <ul id="uploadImagesList">
        <li class="item template">
            <span class="img-wrap">
                <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
            </span>
            <span class="delete-link" title="Удалить">Удалить</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
 
    <div class="clear"></div>
 
 


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Загрузить">



</form>
```

Код предварительного превью и удаления фото до загрузки на сервер.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 
     var maxFileSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024; // (байт) Максимальный размер файла (20мб)
     var queue = {};
     var form = $('form#uploadImages');
     var imagesList = $('#uploadImagesList');
 
     var itemPreviewTemplate = imagesList.find('.item.template').clone();
     itemPreviewTemplate.removeClass('template');
     imagesList.find('.item.template').remove();
 
 
     $('#addImages').on('change', function () {
         var files = this.files;
 
         for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
             var file = files[i];
 
             if ( !file.type.match(/image\/(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)/) ) {
                 alert( 'Фотография должна быть в формате jpg, png или gif' );
                 continue;
             }
 
             if ( file.size > maxFileSize ) {
                 alert( 'Размер фотографии не должен превышать 20 Мб' );
                 continue;
             }
 
             preview(files[i]);
         }
 
         this.value = '';
     });
 
     // Создание превью
     function preview(file) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
             var img = document.createElement('img');
 
             var itemPreview = itemPreviewTemplate.clone();
 
             itemPreview.find('.img-wrap img').attr('src', event.target.result);
             itemPreview.data('id', file.name);
 
             imagesList.append(itemPreview);
 
             queue[file.name] = file;
 
         });
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
 
     // Удаление фотографий
     imagesList.on('click', '.delete-link', function () {
         var item = $(this).closest('.item'),
             id = item.data('id');
 
         delete queue[id];
 
         item.remove();
     });
 
 
     // Отправка формы
     form.on('submit', function(event) {
 
         var formData = new FormData(this);
 
         for (var id in queue) {
             formData.append('images[]', queue[id]);
         }
 
         $.ajax({
             url: $(this).attr('action'),
             type: 'POST',
             data: formData,
             async: true,
             success: function (res) {
                 alert(res)
             },
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false
         });
 
         return false;
     });
 
 });
```

Если ставлю форму загрузки фото  то фото принимаются, как только подключаю превью для картинок перед загрузкой на сервер, снова все пусто.

JS код взят отсюда: https://codd-wd.ru/sozdanie-prevyu-izobrazhenij-s-pomoshhyu-html5-file-api-i-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Так происходит из-за того что `id` вашей формы - `Download`, а но при этом селектор ищет форму с `id="uploadImages"`.

```
var maxFileSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024; // (байт) Максимальный размер файла (20мб)
var queue = {};
var form = $('form#uploadImages');
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  Нужно заменить на form#Download
var imagesList = $('#uploadImagesList');
```

Как следствие не вешается обработчик на событие отправки формы `form.on('submit', function(){});` и происходитпросто отправка, а т.к. после добавления превью `input` обнуляется `this.value = '';`, то в форме отсутствуют файлы

Comment: В очередной раз благодарю за подсказку, но к сожалению этот способ я уже пробовал и он не работает, при нажатии на кнопку submit выводится окно в браузере с частью кода страницы((

Comment: Так а что можно ожидать от `success: function (res) {alert(res)},`? Как бы, у вас указано что при успешной отправке, нужно вывести `alert` с содержимым ответа. Т.е. если `S.php` будет возвращать например имена загруженных файлов, то вы их увидете в `alert`

Comment: Так мне все что нужно чтобы вместе со скриптом массив данных и фотографии отправились, выводить их не нужно в alert'е совершенно. Помогите пожалуйста, для меня пока-что JS как арабский язык когда я на него смотрю.

Comment: Ну так данные формы и фото отправляются, если указать правильный `id`. Просто сейчас суть кода в том, что делается перехват отправки формы и выполняется `ajax` запрос с файлами и всем остальным, а по завершении запроса в `alert` выводится ответ сервера. Т.е. после того как запрос завершился вызывается функция указанная в `success` и сейчас это просто `alert`

Comment: так я указал как вы и подсказали правильный id var form = $('form#Download'); и она и открывает alert и не сохраняет фото при этом загруженные и в принципе не выводит ничего...

Comment: "не сохраняет фото" - Ну так нужно же на принимающей стороне их [сохранять](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-396). "принципе не выводит ничего" - в очередной раз говорю что выводится то, что вы отдаёте. Если сделать `var_dump($_FILES['images']['name']);`, то внезапно в `alert` будут выведены имена загрженых файлов.

Comment: ничего не изменилось, та же ошибка. Alert с частью кода HTML страницы.

Comment: Ещё раз: выводится то, что отдаёт скрипт (в данном случае S.php). Т.е. если у вас в начале html с формой, а потом php код, то естественно в alert вы увидете html, а до вывода из php уже не дойдёт, т.к. банально не влезет. Ну создайте отдельный скрипт в котором будет только `var_dump` из прошлого сообщения и укажите его в `action` - получите в alert желаемый вывод. В конце концов, если уж совсем нет понимания что происходит в коде может стоит пройтись по чуть более простым задачам?